# Extract text from json output of wikipedia api

Tags: python, json, wikipedia-api

I'm having trouble parsing the output of the Wikipedia api in Python. Like a lot of people, I want to isolate bits of text. However, I don't want to use the python wikipedia extension to parse wikis because I want to be able to use other apis and parse their data.

So far I have this:

```
# Import requests package
import requests
import pprint

# Assign URL to variable: url
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&format=json&page=norway&section=7'

# Package the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

# Decode the JSON data into a dictionary: json_data
json_data = r.json()
pprint.pprint(json_data)

# Print the Wikipedia page text
norway_text = json_data['parse']['wikitext']
pprint.pprint(norway_text)
```

The output:

```
{'parse': {'pageid': 21241,
           'title': 'Norway',
           'wikitext': {'*': '=== Viking Age ===\n'
                             '[[File:Le bateau viking dOseberg '
                             '(4835828216).jpg|thumb|upright|The [[Oseberg '
                             'ship]] at the [[Viking Ship Museum (Oslo)|Viking '
                             'Ship Museum]] in [[Oslo]], Norway]]\n'
                             '{{Main article|Viking Age}}\n'
                             '{{See also|Unification of Norway|Hereditary '
                             'Kingdom of Norway}}\n'
                             '[[File:Gjermundbu helmet - '
                             'cropped.jpg|thumb|left|upright=0.7|The '
                             '[[Gjermundbu helmet]] found in [[Buskerud]] is '
                             'the only known reconstructable [[Viking Age]] '
                             'helmet]]\n'
                             '\n'
                             'From the 8th to the 10th century, the wider '
                             'Scandinavian region was the source of '
                             '[[Viking]]s. The looting of the monastery at '
                             '[[Lindisfarne]] in Northeast England in 793 by '
                             '[[Norsemen|Norse people]] has long been regarded '
                             'as the event which marked the beginning of the '
                             '[[Viking Age]].<ref>{{cite web '
                             '|url=http://loststory.net/node/91 |title=Age of '
                             'the vikings |publisher=loststory|accessdate=17 '
                             'February 2015}}</ref> This age was characterised '
                             'by expansion and emigration by Viking '
                             '[[seafarer]]s. They [[colonise]]d, raided, and '
                             'traded in all parts of Europe. Norwegian Viking '
                             'explorers first discovered [[Iceland]] by '
                             'accident in the 9th century when heading for the '
                             '[[Faroe Islands]], and eventually came across '
                             '[[Vinland]], known today as [[Newfoundland '
                             '(island)|Newfoundland]], in [[Canada]]. The '
                             'Vikings from Norway were most active in the '
                             'northern and western [[British Isles]] and '
                             'eastern [[North America]] isles.<ref>{{cite '
                             'web|url=https://naturalhistory.si.edu/vikings/voyage/subset/vinland/archeo.html|title=Vinland '
                             'Archeology|website=naturalhistory.si.edu|access-date=11 '
                             'April 2017}}</ref>\n'
                             '\n'
                             'According to tradition, [[Harald Fairhair]] '
                             'unified them into one in 872 after the [[Battle '
                             'of Hafrsfjord]] in [[Stavanger]], thus becoming '
                             'the first king of a united '
                             'Norway.<ref>[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. 83.</ref> '
                             "Harald's realm was mainly a South Norwegian "
                             'coastal state. Fairhair ruled with a strong hand '
                             'and according to the sagas, many Norwegians left '
                             'the country to live in Iceland, the [[Faroe '
                             'Islands]], [[Greenland]], and parts of [[Great '
                             'Britain|Britain]] and [[Ireland]]. The '
                             'modern-day Irish cities of [[Dublin]], '
                             '[[Limerick]] and [[Waterford]] were founded by '
                             'Norwegian settlers.<ref>[[R. F. Foster '
                             "(historian)|Foster, R. F.]] (2001) ''The Oxford "
                             "History of Ireland''. Oxford University Press. "
                             '{{ISBN|0-19-280202-X}}</ref>\n'
                             '\n'
                             '[[File:Züge, Landnahmen und Siedlungsgebiete der '
                             'Nordmänner - '
                             '800-1050.png|thumb|upright=1.2|Norwegian, Danish '
                             'and Swedish expansion during the Viking age '
                             'between 800–1050]]\n'
                             '\n'
                             '[[Norse mythology|Norse traditions]] were slowly '
                             'replaced by [[Christian mythology|Christian '
                             'ones]] in the late 10th and early 11th '
                             'centuries. One of the most important sources for '
                             'the history of the 11th century Vikings is the '
                             'treaty between the Icelanders and Olaf '
                             'Haraldsson, king of Norway circa 1015 to '
                             '1028.<ref>Jones, Gwyn, A history of the Vikings '
                             '(Oxford 2001).</ref> This is largely attributed '
                             'to the missionary kings [[Olaf I of Norway|Olav '
                             'Tryggvasson]] and [[Olaf II of Norway|St. '
                             'Olav]]. [[Haakon I of Norway|Haakon the Good]] '
                             "was Norway's first Christian king, in the "
                             'mid-10th century, though his attempt to '
                             'introduce the religion was rejected. Born '
                             'sometime in between 963–969, Olav Tryggvasson '
                             'set off raiding in [[England]] with 390 ships. '
                             'He attacked [[London]] during this raiding. '
                             'Arriving back in Norway in 995, Olav landed in '
                             '[[Moster (island)|Moster]]. There he built a '
                             'church which became the first [[Old Moster '
                             'Church|Christian church]] ever built in Norway. '
                             'From Moster, Olav sailed north to [[Trondheim]] '
                             'where he was proclaimed King of Norway by the '
                             'Eyrathing in 995.<ref>[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. '
                             '95.</ref>\n'
                             '\n'
                             '[[Feudalism]] never really developed in Norway '
                             'or Sweden, as it did in the rest of Europe. '
                             'However, the administration of government took '
                             'on a very conservative feudal character. The '
                             '[[Hanseatic League]] forced the royalty to cede '
                             'to them greater and greater concessions over '
                             'foreign trade and the economy. The League had '
                             'this hold over the royalty because of the loans '
                             'the Hansa had made to the royalty and the large '
                             "debt the kings were carrying. The League's "
                             'monopolistic control over the economy of Norway '
                             'put pressure on all classes, especially the '
                             'peasantry, to the degree that no real burgher '
                             'class existed in Norway.<ref>[[#Larsen|Larsen]], '
                             'p. 201.</ref>'}}}
{'*': '=== Viking Age ===\n'
      '[[File:Le bateau viking dOseberg (4835828216).jpg|thumb|upright|The '
      '[[Oseberg ship]] at the [[Viking Ship Museum (Oslo)|Viking Ship '
      'Museum]] in [[Oslo]], Norway]]\n'
      '{{Main article|Viking Age}}\n'
      '{{See also|Unification of Norway|Hereditary Kingdom of Norway}}\n'
      '[[File:Gjermundbu helmet - cropped.jpg|thumb|left|upright=0.7|The '
      '[[Gjermundbu helmet]] found in [[Buskerud]] is the only known '
      'reconstructable [[Viking Age]] helmet]]\n'
      '\n'
      'From the 8th to the 10th century, the wider Scandinavian region was the '
      'source of [[Viking]]s. The looting of the monastery at [[Lindisfarne]] '
      'in Northeast England in 793 by [[Norsemen|Norse people]] has long been '
      'regarded as the event which marked the beginning of the [[Viking '
      'Age]].<ref>{{cite web |url=http://loststory.net/node/91 |title=Age of '
      'the vikings |publisher=loststory|accessdate=17 February 2015}}</ref> '
      'This age was characterised by expansion and emigration by Viking '
      '[[seafarer]]s. They [[colonise]]d, raided, and traded in all parts of '
      'Europe. Norwegian Viking explorers first discovered [[Iceland]] by '
      'accident in the 9th century when heading for the [[Faroe Islands]], and '
      'eventually came across [[Vinland]], known today as [[Newfoundland '
      '(island)|Newfoundland]], in [[Canada]]. The Vikings from Norway were '
      'most active in the northern and western [[British Isles]] and eastern '
      '[[North America]] isles.<ref>{{cite '
      'web|url=https://naturalhistory.si.edu/vikings/voyage/subset/vinland/archeo.html|title=Vinland '
      'Archeology|website=naturalhistory.si.edu|access-date=11 April '
      '2017}}</ref>\n'
      '\n'
      'According to tradition, [[Harald Fairhair]] unified them into one in '
      '872 after the [[Battle of Hafrsfjord]] in [[Stavanger]], thus becoming '
      'the first king of a united Norway.<ref>[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. 83.</ref> '
      "Harald's realm was mainly a South Norwegian coastal state. Fairhair "
      'ruled with a strong hand and according to the sagas, many Norwegians '
      'left the country to live in Iceland, the [[Faroe Islands]], '
      '[[Greenland]], and parts of [[Great Britain|Britain]] and [[Ireland]]. '
      'The modern-day Irish cities of [[Dublin]], [[Limerick]] and '
      '[[Waterford]] were founded by Norwegian settlers.<ref>[[R. F. Foster '
      "(historian)|Foster, R. F.]] (2001) ''The Oxford History of Ireland''. "
      'Oxford University Press. {{ISBN|0-19-280202-X}}</ref>\n'
      '\n'
      '[[File:Züge, Landnahmen und Siedlungsgebiete der Nordmänner - '
      '800-1050.png|thumb|upright=1.2|Norwegian, Danish and Swedish expansion '
      'during the Viking age between 800–1050]]\n'
      '\n'
      '[[Norse mythology|Norse traditions]] were slowly replaced by '
      '[[Christian mythology|Christian ones]] in the late 10th and early 11th '
      'centuries. One of the most important sources for the history of the '
      '11th century Vikings is the treaty between the Icelanders and Olaf '
      'Haraldsson, king of Norway circa 1015 to 1028.<ref>Jones, Gwyn, A '
      'history of the Vikings (Oxford 2001).</ref> This is largely attributed '
      'to the missionary kings [[Olaf I of Norway|Olav Tryggvasson]] and '
      '[[Olaf II of Norway|St. Olav]]. [[Haakon I of Norway|Haakon the Good]] '
      "was Norway's first Christian king, in the mid-10th century, though his "
      'attempt to introduce the religion was rejected. Born sometime in '
      'between 963–969, Olav Tryggvasson set off raiding in [[England]] with '
      '390 ships. He attacked [[London]] during this raiding. Arriving back in '
      'Norway in 995, Olav landed in [[Moster (island)|Moster]]. There he '
      'built a church which became the first [[Old Moster Church|Christian '
      'church]] ever built in Norway. From Moster, Olav sailed north to '
      '[[Trondheim]] where he was proclaimed King of Norway by the Eyrathing '
      'in 995.<ref>[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. 95.</ref>\n'
      '\n'
      '[[Feudalism]] never really developed in Norway or Sweden, as it did in '
      'the rest of Europe. However, the administration of government took on a '
      'very conservative feudal character. The [[Hanseatic League]] forced the '
      'royalty to cede to them greater and greater concessions over foreign '
      'trade and the economy. The League had this hold over the royalty '
      'because of the loans the Hansa had made to the royalty and the large '
      "debt the kings were carrying. The League's monopolistic control over "
      'the economy of Norway put pressure on all classes, especially the '
      'peasantry, to the degree that no real burgher class existed in '
      'Norway.<ref>[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. 201.</ref>'}
```

To begin with, I'd like to isolate the text:

> 'From the 8th to the 10th century, the wider '
>                                'Scandinavian region was the source of '
>                                '[[Viking]]s. The looting of the monastery at '
>                                '[[Lindisfarne]] in Northeast England in 793 by '
>                                '[[Norsemen|Norse people]] has long been regarded '
>                                'as the event which marked the beginning of the '
>                                '[[Viking Age]].{{cite web '
>                                '|url=http://loststory.net/node/91 |title=Age of '
>                                'the vikings |publisher=loststory|accessdate=17 '
>                                'February 2015}} This age was characterised '
>                                'by expansion and emigration by Viking '
>                                '[[seafarer]]s. They [[colonise]]d, raided, and '
>                                'traded in all parts of Europe. Norwegian Viking '
>                                'explorers first discovered [[Iceland]] by '
>                                'accident in the 9th century when heading for the '
>                                '[[Faroe Islands]], and eventually came across '
>                                '[[Vinland]], known today as [[Newfoundland '
>                                '(island)|Newfoundland]], in [[Canada]]. The '
>                                'Vikings from Norway were most active in the '
>                                'northern and western [[British Isles]] and '
>                                'eastern [[North America]] isles.{{cite '
>                                'web|url=https://naturalhistory.si.edu/vikings/voyage/subset/vinland/archeo.html|title=Vinland
>   '
>                                'Archeology|website=naturalhistory.si.edu|access-date=11 '
>                                'April 2017}}\n'
>                                '\n'
>                                'According to tradition, [[Harald Fairhair]] '
>                                'unified them into one in 872 after the [[Battle '
>                                'of Hafrsfjord]] in [[Stavanger]], thus becoming '
>                                'the first king of a united '
>                                'Norway.[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. 83. '
>                                "Harald's realm was mainly a South Norwegian "
>                                'coastal state. Fairhair ruled with a strong hand '
>                                'and according to the sagas, many Norwegians left '
>                                'the country to live in Iceland, the [[Faroe '
>                                'Islands]], [[Greenland]], and parts of [[Great '
>                                'Britain|Britain]] and [[Ireland]]. The '
>                                'modern-day Irish cities of [[Dublin]], '
>                                '[[Limerick]] and [[Waterford]] were founded by '
>                                'Norwegian settlers.[[R. F. Foster '
>                                "(historian)|Foster, R. F.]] (2001) ''The Oxford "
>                                "History of Ireland''. Oxford University Press. "
>                                '{{ISBN|0-19-280202-X}}\n'
>                                '\n'
>                                '[[File:Züge, Landnahmen und Siedlungsgebiete der '
>                                'Nordmänner - '
>                                '800-1050.png|thumb|upright=1.2|Norwegian, Danish '
>                                'and Swedish expansion during the Viking age '
>                                'between 800–1050]]\n'
>                                '\n'
>                                '[[Norse mythology|Norse traditions]] were slowly '
>                                'replaced by [[Christian mythology|Christian '
>                                'ones]] in the late 10th and early 11th '
>                                'centuries. One of the most important sources for '
>                                'the history of the 11th century Vikings is the '
>                                'treaty between the Icelanders and Olaf '
>                                'Haraldsson, king of Norway circa 1015 to '
>                                '1028.Jones, Gwyn, A history of the Vikings '
>                                '(Oxford 2001). This is largely attributed '
>                                'to the missionary kings [[Olaf I of Norway|Olav '
>                                'Tryggvasson]] and [[Olaf II of Norway|St. '
>                                'Olav]]. [[Haakon I of Norway|Haakon the Good]] '
>                                "was Norway's first Christian king, in the "
>                                'mid-10th century, though his attempt to '
>                                'introduce the religion was rejected. Born '
>                                'sometime in between 963–969, Olav Tryggvasson '
>                                'set off raiding in [[England]] with 390 ships. '
>                                'He attacked [[London]] during this raiding. '
>                                'Arriving back in Norway in 995, Olav landed in '
>                                '[[Moster (island)|Moster]]. There he built a '
>                                'church which became the first [[Old Moster '
>                                'Church|Christian church]] ever built in Norway. '
>                                'From Moster, Olav sailed north to [[Trondheim]] '
>                                'where he was proclaimed King of Norway by the '
>                                'Eyrathing in 995.[[#Larsen|Larsen]], p. '
>                                '95.\n'
>                                '\n'
>                                '[[Feudalism]] never really developed in Norway '
>                                'or Sweden, as it did in the rest of Europe. '
>                                'However, the administration of government took '
>                                'on a very conservative feudal character. The '
>                                '[[Hanseatic League]] forced the royalty to cede '
>                                'to them greater and greater concessions over '
>                                'foreign trade and the economy. The League had '
>                                'this hold over the royalty because of the loans '
>                                'the Hansa had made to the royalty and the large '
>                                "debt the kings were carrying. The League's "
>                                'monopolistic control over the economy of Norway '
>                                'put pressure on all classes, especially the '
>                                'peasantry, to the degree that no real burgher '
>                                'class existed in Norway.

If possible, I'd also like to extract a list of links?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mwparserfromhell](https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to get links, template parameters etc. from the wikitext.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you've got a solid chunk of pure text there so it's going to take some bespoke code to extract what you want. Not complex however.

To start with you can extract the text you want with:

```
txt = json_data['parse']['wikitext']['*']
```

In which I take it the '*' means 'all'. Then to get the url's - it looks like every url ends with a space. Assuming this convention holds and that you aren't bothered about keeping the text intact, each url can be extract like this:

```
urls = []

while "url=" in txt:
    start = txt.find("url=") + 4
    end = txt.find(' ', start)

    url = txt[start:end]
    urls.append(url)

    txt = txt[end:]
```

This code basically finds the first url in the text and extracts it, then chops that url and the rest of the text before it out of the txt object so the next url found will be the next one along and so on, until no more urls remain. Your urls are then stored in the list 'urls'. If you need to keep the text unchanged then create another object before extract the urls using the above code.

Comment: `*` means something like "content"; a long time ago the default API output used XML, and the text was inside `<wikitext>`, and the JSON output needed to differentiate between the contents of that tag and attributes in that tag and ended up with an object containing the attributes as fields and the content as the `*` field. You can get a less convoluted output using [`formatversion=2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=wikitext&format=jsonfm&formatversion=2&page=norway&section=7).

Comment: Trying to parse markup using regular expressions is usually a bad idea, and this is not an exception.